# ReferenceError: React is not defined in svg file

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs, webpack, mocha.js

I import svg in my React application with svg-react-loader. When I test my components with mocha I get the exception:

```
pure/landing-assets/logo.svg:3
React.createElement(
^

ReferenceError: React is not defined
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Have you defined react in mocha?

Comment: @rnli Did you mean in test file or in mocha.opts?

Comment: having this problem right now as well.  8 hours after you.  I'll let you know if I find anything

Comment: ok, well, I found in my case that I had removed the namespaces from the svg because that was causing problems.  When I put the namespaces back in I stopped getting that area.  I still can't get my tests running though.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? Currently running into the same issue.

Comment: @Prefix Yes. I used react-svg-inline library for SVG in my app

Answer (score -3):

Please declare and require React before your script load, javascript is case senistive.

```
var React = require('react');
```